# Change Label text in gridview on checking checkbox

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am using this Gridview which have checkboxes and labels in it.Now I want when i click the checkbox the text of label must change.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdData" runat="server" style="Text-align:center;">
  <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="changeTextValue(this)"/>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <HeaderTemplate>
  <%--<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" OnClick="CheckAllEmp(this)"/>--%>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField>
  <HeaderTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="Status_Header" runat="server" Text="Status" />
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=0 ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What you have tried? Show some attempted code.

Comment: I created Javascript function

    function changeTextValue(chk)
 {
    var currentTextID = $(chk).parents('tr').find('input[type="Label"]     [id$="Label1"]');
          
            if (chk.checked == true)
                currentTextID.val(1);
            else
                currentTextID.val(0);
        }

Comment: can you post the html of gridview when you view the page in the browser? In the browser, you can right-click on the page, and choose View Source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Question**

Because the label rendered on html will be：

```
<span id="grdData_ctl02_Label1" ClientIDMode="Static">1</span>
```

So,you should use "span[id*='Label1']" to find it out：

```
function changeTextValue(chk) {
    var currentTextID = $(chk).parents("tr").find("span[id*='Label1']");
    if (chk.checked == true) {
        currentTextID.html(1);
    }
    else {
        currentTextID.html(0);
    }
}
```

**Second Question**

Gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="changeTextValue(this)" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" OnClick="CheckAllEmp(this)" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Javascript

```
function CheckAllEmp(chk) {
    var currentTextID = $(chk).parents("table").find("span[id*='Label1']");
    var childCheckBoxID = $(chk).parents("table").find("input[id*='CheckBox1']");
    if (chk.checked == true) {
        currentTextID.html(1);
        childCheckBoxID.prop("checked", true);
    }
    else {
        currentTextID.html(0);
        childCheckBoxID.prop("checked", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Angus for your answer.
Your Code is Working Perfectly.
Help me in one more thing Now i want one header checkbox and on checking all checkbox in item template should get checked and text of label should change to 1 from 0.and on unchecking to 0 from 1.

please help me in this. I dont have any clue how to do this.

Comment: Thanks,
one more question arises when i am saving the value in database is is taking the same value without any updation

Comment: Thanks @Angus Chund Your Code is WOrking Perfectly

Answer (score 0):

For what reason do you use ClientIDMode="Static"?

You have to create function CheckAllEmp(this) event in your_program_file.cs.
Code in that function would be smth like that:

```
CheckAllEmp(...){
  Label1.Text="Something new";
}
```

Comment: I have multiple rows in gridview so that every row must have same id thats why i used ClientIDMode ="Static"

Answer (score 0):

When you want this kind of operations on GridView, it is always good to check the html source of your page. In this scenario, for example, you will have the following html code for your gridview:

```
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="grdData" style="border-collapse:collapse;text-align: center;">
       <tr>
            <th scope="col"></th>
            <th scope="col">
               <span id="grdData_Status_Header">Status</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
               <input id="grdData_CheckBox1_0" type="checkbox" name="grdData$ctl02$CheckBox1" onclick="changeTextValue(this);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="Label1">Unique Perspective</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="grdData_CheckBox1_1" type="checkbox" name="grdData$ctl03$CheckBox1" onclick="changeTextValue(this);" />
            </td>
            <td>
                 <span id="Label1">Challenging</span>
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

As you may see, checkbox and label controls are in adjacent table cells. You can use `.parent().next()` to access the cell containing the label control. Also, you may see that label was rendered as span. To get the label control, therefore, you can use: `.parent().next().find('span')`. One final note is that you can use `.text` property of a span to change its contents. See the whole script below:

```
    function changeTextValue(chk) {
        var currentTextID = $(chk).parent().next().find('span');
        if (chk.checked == true)
            currentTextID.text('1');
        else currentTextID.text('0');
    }
```

Comment: next().find('span') will affect all Label if has "Label2","Label3" etc.

Comment: @AngusChung yes I agree, but in the current scenario it won't since user2747666 considered one label.